Developer options not showing up in overlay
I have enabled Developer Extras in Blender Preferences > Interface > Display, but it will not show up in my Overlay drop down? I need to enable vertex IDs so I can fix a weight issue, but cant fix it till I fix this bug.


Figured it out. I think I needed to be in edit mode with vertex selection mode enabled and I was looking in the wrong drop down.

